# How to set alarm from ListView inside Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio

here is my `OnClick` Activity

```
lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lst, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Intent intent1;
         //   int itemPosition=lst.;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
```

I would want to add my action point at every case:

Comment: plz explain your question....

Comment: Im sorry I am a beginner, I have created a custom listview  using adapterview, However, I want to create OnClick activity that allows user to set Alarm to certain time of day, for example an alarm rings every 8am everyday.  So when user selects position 0 for instance which is case 0: the app automatically sets a predefined alarm clock, like a reminder. Thanks in advance